# Facing issue while using Sass in angular latest version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\balaji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (F:\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (F:\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F:\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134

gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd F:\angular\invoice-processing-office\invoice-proccessing\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass

gyp ERR! node -v v10.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I have tried `npm install node-sass` but no luck.

Comment: According to the error, you need to install python first.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1176

Comment: already I have installed python